# Why is this query answered instantly by the sqlite3 application, but slowly using sqlitejdbc?

Tags: sqlite, sqlitejdbc

I'm using Mac OS X v10.4.11 with the standard Java (1.5.0_19) and sqlite3 (3.1.3) that came it.  (**Yeah, a little old... but see comment below**.)

I have a sqlite3 database with a table with a few hundred thousand rows, with "name" and "stored" text columns.  Name is one of six (so far) short strings; stored is a 19-character standard date-time string.  Each column has a stand-alone index.  There are only six unique name values.  The following query:

```
select distinct name from myTable where stored >= date("now");
```

lists the relevant names instantly when I perform it through the Mac OS X "sqlite3" application.  But it takes over 2 seconds to find each name (total of about 15 seconds) when I do the same thing in the usual way in my application:

```
String         q = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM myTable " +
                    "WHERE stored >= DATE('now');" ;
try {
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(q);
    while (rs.next()) {
        final String s = rs.getString("symbol");
        System.err.println("Got " + s);
    }
    rs.close();
}
```

I've tried this with both sqlitejdbc-v054 and sqlitejdbc-v055 .  No perceptible difference.

Is this a known deficiency?  If not, anyone have any suggestions how to attack it ?

Comment: Do they both return the same expected results?

Comment: Terribly sorry not to reply sooner; I didn't get notified of your response.  The answer is yes, same results.

Comment: Over the weekend I upgraded to Mac OS X v10.5.8, Java 1.5.0_22, sqlite3 3.4.0, and sqlitejdbc v056.

No perceptible difference in behavior; the sqlite3 app still responds instantly, and the java program that uses sqlitejdbc still takes 10 seconds to complete the same query.